# Azure function app showing error Stack Overflow exception

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have created Event Grid function trigger and deployed on Function App, but after few days its showing me below error, also in between days i am deploying code by pipeline.

> We identified the below thread resulted in a **Stack Overflow Exception** for your App azfunc-dev and application code should be fixed to prevent impact to application availability.

here **azfunc-dev** is my function app name.

I have tried different solution like Stop and Start my Function app also Restart.

i am pasting below screen shot of exception, from azure side not providing any other detail.

[image: StackoverflowException]

after this exception still i can able to call this function app, and it is executing successfully.
this exception shows in **Overview** of Function App

[image]

could you please help me here it would really appreciate.

Comment: Could you please let us know by using VS you have published your function app or created on portal itself.

Comment: no, we are using Azure devops pipeline for deployment

Comment: Could you please refer this https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-durable-extension/issues/1077

Comment: Also may i know is there any infinite loop or infinite recursion in your function app code.

Comment: we use durable function, as one durable function call another this things we are doing

Comment: is this because of recursion it showing this type of error, for example: if any error of recursion found then how to resolve this error without deleting function app, is any way ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242358/discussion-between-ajaykumarghose-mt-and-lalji-dhameliya).

Comment: @AjayKumarGhose-MT in non durable function same error found